# Codeigniter, xampp cookies not setting

Tags: php, codeigniter, cookies, xampp

I'm using the codeigniter with xampp on a windows 7 PC.

I'm trying to use codeigniter's built in cookies, but I can't seem to get my cookies to set/stay. I know that the cookie code is going off, it's just not actually saving.

Here's the cookie code:

```
$this->input->set_cookie('userID', $userID, time()+259200, 'http://localhost', '/');
```

After running this and on every page, I've included `print_r($_COOKIE);` to see any/all cookies that are being set, but nothing shows up.

Is there something I've missed?

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs:

> The expiration is set in seconds, which will be added to the current
>   time. Do not include the time, but rather only the number of seconds
>   from now that you wish the cookie to be valid. If the expiration is
>   set to zero the cookie will only last as long as the browser is open.

So your code should be like this:

```
$this->input->set_cookie('userID', $userID, 259200);
```

Also i recommend you to set domain name and cookie path in the config file.

Comment: I tried doing as you said. I set the following up in my config.php:
`$config['cookie_domain'] = "http://localhost";`
`$config['cookie_path']  = "/";`

And changed to `$this->input->set_cookie('userID', $userID, 259200);` and it's still not setting at all.

It should be noted that the method I originally used has worked for me on other domains, it simply won't for localhost

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution for anyone else that runs into this problem:

Cookies cannot be created on localhost, you'll need to use `http://127.0.0.1` instead.

Go into CI's application/config/config.php and change any references to localhost you might have and change them instead to `http://127.0.0.1` and do the same for the cookies. Set the following variables as well:

```
$config['cookie_domain']    = "127.0.0.1";
$config['cookie_path']      = "/";
```

Then to store the cookie: `$this->input->set_cookie('userID', $userID, 259200);`